# std::ostream interface to an OLE IStream

Tags: c++, istream, streambuf

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application using [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28VS.85%29.aspx)s. I would like to use the IStream connection in a `std::ostream`. Something like this:

```
IStream* stream = /*create valid IStream instance...*/; 
IStreamBuf< WIN32_FIND_DATA > sb( stream );
std::ostream os( &sb );

WIN32_FIND_DATA d = { 0 };
// send the structure along the IStream
os << d;
```

To accomplish this, I've implemented the following code:

```
template< class _CharT, class _Traits >
inline std::basic_ostream< _CharT, _Traits >& 
operator<<( std::basic_ostream< _CharT, _Traits >& os, const WIN32_FIND_DATA& i ) 
{
    const _CharT* c = reinterpret_cast< const _CharT* >( &i );
    const _CharT* const end = c + sizeof( WIN32_FIND_DATA ) / sizeof( _CharT );
    for( c; c < end; ++c ) os << *c;
    return os;
}

template< typename T >
class IStreamBuf : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    IStreamBuf( IStream* stream ) : stream_( stream )
    {
        setp( reinterpret_cast< char* >( &buffer_ ), 
              reinterpret_cast< char* >( &buffer_ ) + sizeof( buffer_ ) );
    };

    virtual ~IStreamBuf()
    {
        sync();
    };

protected:
    traits_type::int_type FlushBuffer()
    {
        int bytes = std::min< int >( pptr() - pbase(), sizeof( buffer_ ) );

        DWORD written = 0;
        HRESULT hr = stream_->Write( &buffer_, bytes, &written );
        if( FAILED( hr ) )
        {
            return traits_type::eof();
        }

        pbump( -bytes );
        return bytes;
    };

    virtual int sync()
    {
        if( FlushBuffer() == traits_type::eof() )
            return -1;
        return 0;
    };

    traits_type::int_type overflow( traits_type::int_type ch )
    {
        if( FlushBuffer() == traits_type::eof() )
            return traits_type::eof();

        if( ch != traits_type::eof() )
        {
            *pptr() = ch;
            pbump( 1 );
        }

        return ch;
    };

private:
    /// data queued up to be sent
    T buffer_;

    /// output stream
    IStream* stream_;
}; // class IStreamBuf
```

Yes, the code compiles and seems to work, but I've not had the pleasure of implementing a `std::streambuf` before. So, I'd just like to know if it's correct and complete.

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: Besides your point, I know, but I still have to get it off my chest: You `operator<<` makes me cringe. `<<` isn't meant for binary output, it's for textual output. Three years from now, someone maintaining this code write `std::cerr << "value of x: " << x '\n'` for debugging and the guys sharing his office get testy, when it turns out `x` is not what he thought, but some `struct` that gets streamed in binary, with `\07` bells, whistles and all.

Comment: @sbi - what do you recommend? I thought the `std::streambuf` class required an overloaded `operator<<` to work.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just feel bad about using `operator<<` for streaming out binary stuff. Maybe that's all the rage now, and I have missed the hype, but it used to be only used for textual output. That is what streams actually __do__, after all: the formatting needed to stream binary data as text. The rest (buffering and actual device IO) is left for stream buffers.

Comment: @sbi - since this is binary data, what if I changed it from a `std::streambuf` to a `std::basic_streambuf< byte >` and fix my `std::basic_ostream<>` template at `std::basic_ostream<byte>`. That would mean you couldn't accidentally `std::cerr << "value of x: " << x '\n'`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation I wrote a while ago: https://github.com/senderista/UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf

For the most part you just need to mechanically translate between STL and Windows/COM types. This translation is tedious and error-prone, though, so you would probably be best off using the implementation I linked. It's only 150 lines, it was used in a production application, and there are few places for bugs to hide.

Since apparently links in answers are cause for deletion, here's the code in its entirety:

```
//Copyright (c) 2010 Tobin Baker
//
//Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
//of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
//in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
//to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
//furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
//The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
//all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
//AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
//LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
//OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
//THE SOFTWARE.


#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <windows.h>

// Read-write unbuffered streambuf implementation which uses no
// internal buffers (conventional wisdom says this can't be done
// except for write-only streams, but I adapted Matt Austern's example
// from http://www.drdobbs.com/184401305).

class UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf : public std::streambuf {
public:
    UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf(IStream *stream, std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    ~UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf();

protected:
    virtual int overflow(int ch = traits_type::eof());
    virtual int underflow();
    virtual int uflow();
    virtual int pbackfail(int ch = traits_type::eof());
    virtual int sync();
    virtual std::streampos seekpos(std::streampos sp, std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    virtual std::streampos seekoff(std::streamoff off, std::ios_base::seekdir way, std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    virtual std::streamsize xsgetn(char *s, std::streamsize n);
    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize n);
    virtual std::streamsize showmanyc();

private:
    IStream *stream_;
    bool readOnly_;
    bool backup();
};

UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf(IStream *stream, std::ios_base::openmode which)
: std::streambuf(), stream_(stream), readOnly_(!(which & std::ios_base::out)) {}

UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::~UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf() { if (!readOnly_) UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::sync(); }

bool UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::backup() {
    LARGE_INTEGER liMove;
    liMove.QuadPart = -1LL;
    return SUCCEEDED(stream_->Seek(liMove, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, NULL));
}

int UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::overflow(int ch) {
    if (ch != traits_type::eof()) {
        if (SUCCEEDED(stream_->Write(&ch, 1, NULL))) {
            return ch;
        }
    }
    return traits_type::eof();
}

int UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::underflow() {
    char ch = UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::uflow();
    if (ch != traits_type::eof()) {
        ch = backup() ? ch : traits_type::eof();
    }
    return ch;
}

int UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::uflow() {
    char ch;
    ULONG cbRead;
    // S_FALSE indicates we've reached end of stream
    return (S_OK == stream_->Read(&ch, 1, &cbRead))
        ? ch : traits_type::eof();
}

int UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::pbackfail(int ch) {
    if (ch != traits_type::eof()) {
        ch = backup() ? ch : traits_type::eof();
    }
    return ch;
}

int UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::sync() {
    return SUCCEEDED(stream_->Commit(STGC_DEFAULT)) ? 0 : -1;
}

std::ios::streampos UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::seekpos(std::ios::streampos sp, std::ios_base::openmode which) {
    LARGE_INTEGER liMove;
    liMove.QuadPart = sp;
    return SUCCEEDED(stream_->Seek(liMove, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL)) ? sp : -1;
}

std::streampos UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::seekoff(std::streamoff off, std::ios_base::seekdir way, std::ios_base::openmode which) {
    STREAM_SEEK sk;
    switch (way) {
        case std::ios_base::beg: sk = STREAM_SEEK_SET; break;
        case std::ios_base::cur: sk = STREAM_SEEK_CUR; break;
        case std::ios_base::end: sk = STREAM_SEEK_END; break;
        default: return -1;
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER liMove;
    liMove.QuadPart = static_cast<LONGLONG>(off);
    ULARGE_INTEGER uliNewPos;
    return SUCCEEDED(stream_->Seek(liMove, sk, &uliNewPos))
        ? static_cast<std::streampos>(uliNewPos.QuadPart) : -1;
}

std::streamsize UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::xsgetn(char *s, std::streamsize n) {
    ULONG cbRead;
    return SUCCEEDED(stream_->Read(s, static_cast<ULONG>(n), &cbRead))
        ? static_cast<std::streamsize>(cbRead) : 0;
}

std::streamsize UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::xsputn(const char *s, std::streamsize n) {
    ULONG cbWritten;
    return SUCCEEDED(stream_->Write(s, static_cast<ULONG>(n), &cbWritten))
        ? static_cast<std::streamsize>(cbWritten) : 0;
}

std::streamsize UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf::showmanyc() {
    STATSTG stat;
    if (SUCCEEDED(stream_->Stat(&stat, STATFLAG_NONAME))) {
        std::streampos lastPos = static_cast<std::streampos>(stat.cbSize.QuadPart - 1);
        LARGE_INTEGER liMove;
        liMove.QuadPart = 0LL;
        ULARGE_INTEGER uliNewPos;
        if (SUCCEEDED(stream_->Seek(liMove, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, &uliNewPos))) {
            return std::max<std::streamsize>(lastPos - static_cast<std::streampos>(uliNewPos.QuadPart), 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

std::streambuf* StdStreamBufFromOLEStream(IStream *pStream, std::ios_base::openmode which)
{
    return new (std::nothrow) UnbufferedOLEStreamBuf(pStream, which);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use [`Boost.IOStreams`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) `Device` to wrap the `IStream`. It takes care of all of the C++ IO streams stuff so that you do not have to.